# Print the reverse of an arrow pattern in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Right now this code gives me:

```
*
 *
  *
   *
```

And I can't seem to figure out how to get the arrow finish off (in other words reversing the first print):

```
*
 *
  *
   *
   *
  *
 *
*
```

--

```
columns = int(input("How many columns? "))

while columns <= 0:
    print ("Invalid entry, try again!")
    columns = int(input("How many columns? "))

x = 1
for x in range(columns):
        for x in range(x):print(" ", end="")
        print("*")
```

Comment: Why you tagged `design-patterns` ? THIS IS NOT DESIGN PATTERN!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run loop backwards after your first loop finished. [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) can take three parameters. start, stop, step. With step, you can move backwards.

```
for x in range(1, columns):
    for x in range(x):
        print(" ", end="")
    print("*")

for x in range(columns,0,-1): 
    for x in range(x):
        print(" ", end="")
    print("*")
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

1 - I construct the list of values to adjust position of `*` in the `print`, using [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.chain) from `itertools`
2 - While iterating through the list, I pass the adjustment value to `str.rjust`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> col = int(input('Enter nb of columns:'))
Enter nb of columns:7
>>> l = chain(range(1,col), range(col,0,-1))
>>> 
>>> for x in l:
    print('*'.rjust(x))


*
 *
  *
   *
    *
     *
      *
     *
    *
   *
  *
 *
*
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first section (first half) just add space as it's index and for second half add space and decrease each iterate :

```
 for x in range(columns):
        if(x<(columns//2)):print (" "*x+"*")
        else : print(" "*(-x+(columns-1))+"*")

 columns = 8  

*
 *
  *
   *
   *
  *
 *
*

columns = 7   

*
 *
  *
   *
  *
 *
*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v = [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]

col = int(input('Enter nb of columns:'))
for x in range(1, col):
    for i in range(0,x):
        v[x] = "*"
    print x * " " ,v[x]
x = col
for x in range(x, 0, -1):
    for i in range(x,0,-1):
        v[x] = "*"
    print x * " " ,v[x]
```